# Animate Menu Collapsed - Menu Expanded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I want is that when I click on the button, the COLLAPSE menu has a different width and its content also changes its properties (in this case change the font size), When I press the button for the first time, the content changes its size, but when I press it the second time to EXPAND the menu, the content does not recover its properties. I want to do it with the ANIMATE property in JavaScript because the change of properties is not very abrupt.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('#sidebar');


$('#menu-btn').click(function() {
  var width = $('#sidebar').width();
  if (width == 100) {
    $('#sidebar').animate({
      width: "50"
    });
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-collapsed");
  } else {
    $('#sidebar').animate({
      width: "100"
    });
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-expanded");
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-expanded {
  width: 100px;
}

li a {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#menu-btn {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.menu-collapsed {
  width: 50px;
}

.menu-collapsed a {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul id="sidebar" class="menu-expanded">
    <li id="li"><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ex, voluptatum error itaque provident totam ratione, quaerat reprehenderit accusantium omnis veniam voluptatibus fugiat ducimus, eos, consequuntur perferendis fugit adipisci dolores.
  </div>
</div>

<button id="menu-btn">MENU</button>
```

Comment: Please post in English, or to post in Spanish, use [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Use a free service like Google translate and maybe I can help.

Comment: @FSDford Asking a question on StackOverflow, if the only way to do that is an automatic translator and the use of help offered by other users is questionable. Many users are convinced that any non-trivial question can only be answerd with feedback by the asker on comments they receive. That is unlikely to work without friction, if an auto translator is in the middle - and even less if waiting for another user is necessary. So, this is only my opinioni, but I do recommend to not ask users to autotranslate and even less offering them to help.

Comment: Why not just remove all the language from the question and go from there?

Comment: I just made an edit to your snippet that I think solves your problem.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS I rolled back the edit. If you want to answer the question then please post the solution in the answer space